# How do I create a file descriptor in linux that can be read from multiple processes without consuming the data?

Tags: linux, ipc, pipe, file-descriptor, io-redirection

I'd like to create a file descriptor that when written to can be read from multiple processes without consuming the data.  I'm aware of named pipes, but since it's a fifo, only one processes can ever get the data.

My use case is the following.  With git, hooks use stdin to pass data to be processed into the hook.  I want to be able to call multiple sub-hooks from a parent hook.  Each sub-hook should get the same stdin data as the parent receives.  If I'm not mistaken when I use a pipe, then each subprocess will not get the same stdin.  Instead, the first hook to read stdin would consume the data.  Is this correct?

The only option I really see being viable at this point is writing stdin to a file then reading that file from each subprocess.  Is there another way?

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you could try to use tee.

From man tee:

```
tee - read from standard input and write to standard output and files
```

In your case with processes in this way: `tee >(parent) >(hook1) >(hook2) >(hookn)`

(where each hook is a different process, command, shell whatever you want)

Here an example:

```
#!/bin/bash

while read stdinstream
do
    echo -n ${stdinstream} | tee >(parent) >(hook2) >(hook1)
done
```

EDIT:

In your case I do not think you are going to need the while loop, with this could be enough:

```
read stdinstream
echo -n ${stdinstream} | tee >(parent) >(hook2) >(hook1)
```

Hopefully this will help you.

Comment: Unfortunately this didn't work for my usecase (python hook using subprocess).  The easiest solution was to write stdin out to a file then pass the file into each hook simulating stdin.  I wish there was a multicast pipe in linux though, that would be cool.